# How to test custom error from inherited contract?

Tags: custom-errors

contract1.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

abstract contract Contract1 {
    error Error1(address account);
}
```

contract2.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Contract1} from "./contract1.sol";

contract Contract2 is Contract1 {    
    error Error2(address account);

    function customError1() public view {
        revert Error1(msg.sender);
    }

    function customError2() public view {
        revert Error2(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

test script:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Contract2} from "../src/contract2.sol";

contract ErrorTest is Test {
    Contract2 public contract2;

    function setUp() public {
        contract2 = new Contract2();
    }

    function test_customError1() public {
        vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSelector(Contract2.Error1.selector, msg.sender));
        vm.prank(address(123));
        contract2.customError1();
    }

    function test_customError2() public {
        vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSelector(Contract2.Error2.selector, msg.sender));
        vm.prank(address(123));
        contract2.customError2();
    }
}
```

Error Message：

```
Error: 
Compiler run failed:
Error (9582): Member "Error1" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract Contract2).
  --> test/test.t.sol:15:48:
   |
15 |         vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSelector(Contract2.Error1.selector, msg.sender));
   |
```

Test for error 2 is OK, but not for error 1. Please assist. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Just "import contract1" and use "contract1.Error1" will be able to solve this issue.

Comment: Yeah seeing this now. That's great. I've deleted my answer, so as to avoid any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help, man.